# Can't unwrap/cast in in Swift 3

Tags: ios, casting, swift3, option-type, unwrap

I'm using the ios library Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

There's a delegate function declared `chartValueSelected`, which gives me back `entry: ChartDataEntry`.

So I get the `entry`, with it's `data`, declared as `var data: AnyObject?`

```
print(entry.data)
> Optional(Optional(<MyProject.Stop: 0x6000002c5cc0> (entity: Stop; id: 0xd00000000c980010 <x-coredata://5F54CCEC-11FB-42F1-BDFE-30F7F7E18614/Stop/p806> ; data: { ...  })))

print(type(of: entry.data))
> Optional<AnyObject>
```

That's wierd? I assigned it a non optional? Well, that might be a bug in the library, but I should atleast be able to access it?

```
guard let e = stopEntry as? Stop else {
    continue
}

yVal.append(BarChartDataEntry(value: e.duration!.doubleValue, xIndex: i, data: e))
```

Well, we're fine with the `??` double optional.. But what? Why cant we unwrap it?

```
if let hasObject = entry.data {
    print("We have object: \(type(of: hasObject))")
    > We have object: _SwiftValue
    if let stopObject = hasObject as? Stop {
        print("We have a stop object!!") // Doesnt come here
    }
}
```

More things that doesnt work are:

```
if let s = entry.data, let b = s as? Stop {
    // Not executed here either
}
```